# Seeing text on ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, font, virtual-machine

I can't use my ArcGIS Pro software. The font color is white, when the background is white.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that's odd. Try changing your windows colour scheme, high contrast perhaps, the colours *should* be based on your system defined colours. If that doesn't work it's probably reinstall time.

Comment: Ah, well, High Contrast works. Thanks! It isn't pretty but I'll take it for now.

Comment: So that's found the source of the problem, now when you have a lazy few minutes you can flick through system colour schemes until you find one you like that doesn't produce white on white (or black on black) text for ArcGIS Pro. Does the change of colour scheme change immediately or do you need to restart ArcGIS Pro to test the new colours? Can you please answer your own question (yes, it's legal and encouraged) with your experience and some screen shots for future users with the same problem.

Comment: Are you running Arc Pro on Bootcamp or via remote desktop?

Comment: Yes, VirtualBox @Aaron

Comment: I suspect this is related to your virtual environment. Try running Arc Pro and Windows on Bootcamp: https://support.apple.com/boot-camp

Answer (score 0):

Go to the dark mode theme in Pro settings:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/general-options.htm